# python sqlite3 parameterization - insert throws no such column error

Tags: python, database, sqlite

Insert in columns with parameterized query throws **no such column** error

**First (working) example:**

```
        # unit test input
        name = "issue_number_1"
        text = "issue_text"
        rating_sum = 0

        if name:

            # check if issue is already in db
            with self.conn:  # this should release the connection when finished
                test = cursor.execute("SELECT name, text FROM issue WHERE name = ?", (name,))
                data = test.fetchall()
                print(data)
```

this is working and prints:

```
[('issue_number_1', 'issue_text')]
```

**Second (non working) example:**

```
        # unit test input
        name = "issue_number_2"
        text = "issue_text"
        rating_sum = 0

        if name:

            with self.conn:
                sql_string = "INSERT INTO issue (name, text, rating_sum) VALUES (name = ?, text = ?, rating_sum = ?)"
                cursor.execute(sql_string, (name, text, rating_sum,))
```

throws this error:

```
cursor.execute(sql_string, (name, text, rating_sum,))
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: name
```

- the column name exists, the first example proofed that
- the name: "issue_number_2" does not exist in the DB
- the second example fails exactly same with only name to insert (only one parameter)
- i had no problems inserting with string concatenation so the problem should be in my second example code somewhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of experiments i was a little bit confused....

**This is the right syntax:**

```
 sql_string = "INSERT INTO issue (name, text, rating_sum) VALUES (?, ?, ?)"
 cursor.execute(sql_string, (name, text, rating_sum,))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add single quote.for example:

```
"INSERT INTO table (field) VALUES ('$1')"
```

add just values in second () and add single quote around string values.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it is not the solution, i got it myself. :D - but its a good tip anyway to use single quotes for these strings.

Answer (score 0):

The statement:

```
INSERT INTO .... VALUES ....
```

is an SQL statement and the correct syntax is:

```
INSERT INTO tablename (col1, col2, ...) VALUES (expr1, expr2, ...)
```

where `col1, col2, ...` are columns of the table `tablename` and `expr1, expr2, ...` are expressions or literals that are evaluated and assigned to each of the columns `col1, col2, ...` respectively.

So the syntax that you use is not valid SQL syntax.
The assignment of the values is not performed inside `VALUES(...)`.
The correct syntax to use in Python would be:

```
INSERT INTO issue (name, text, rating_sum) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
```

Comment: Thanks for the Answer anyway! :D